# Histogram black magic - ggplot vs base R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm simulating some data where I randomly sample values between 1 and 100, and then I am plotting a histogram of the data (this is just a preamble to a real simulation where I compare a random distribution to a biased one).

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
data_bkd <- tibble(group='bkd', 
                pos=sample(1:100, 1001, replace=T))

hist(data_bkd$pos, breaks=5, border='black', xlab='pos')

ggplot(data_bkd, aes(x=pos)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=5, fill='gray', col='black') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
If I use the base R `hist` function, I get what I expect. But if I use ggplot `geom_histogram`, I get a very unorthodox representation of my data, suggesting underrepresentation of both low and high numbers, which is definitely not the case.

```
cut(data_bkd$pos, breaks=c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100)) %>% table()
.
  (0,20]  (20,40]  (40,60]  (60,80] (80,100] 
     192      224      188      189      208
```

I find no noticeable difference if I play with the number of bins plotted, play with the x-axis breaks via `scale_x_continuous`, or change the total number of calls in my simulation. How can I make `geom_histogram` behave like its base R equivalent, and give an accurate representation of my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case don't rely on `geom_histogram()`'s `bin`, but rather on its `breaks` parameter.

Try:

```
ggplot(data_bkd, aes(x=pos)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0,100, by = 20), 
                 fill='gray', col='black') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and worked as you showed. I'm very puzzled by why the default `geom_histogram` behavior would be to set the breaks elsewhere, it seems to invalidate the whole concept of a histogram to distort the data in that way.

Comment: I know! 
My guess is that (1) because `geom_histogram()` has many more parameters to control the bins than `hist()`, and (2) `ggplot2` tries to use a common grammar for all its `geom_*` functions, they decided to control this behavior trough `breaks`, just like they do for the scales. See https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/breaks_extended.html